# Unable to install an R Bioconductor package on Apple M1/M2

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have an Apple latest arm64 machine. Running the latest R 4.3.0 version. However, I'm unable to install an R package - `S4Arrays`.

[image]

Doesn't look like there is an arm64 build for this package. Anybody know how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you please paste your error message as text into your question? Images of text are difficult to read, and harder for screen readers to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to install the x86 version of R in your M1/M2 Mac [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/base/R-4.3.0-x86_64.pkg).
It will be then emulated by the Rosetta. After that you will have no problems with Bioconductor packages

Comment: This is a huge pain once one goes down the ARM path for R and libs. I had to revert back when BioC did not support ARM but now, there are other hacks.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a pain! However R 4.3 is out for a couple of week, forcing you anyway to start from scratch with the packages' installation, in this situation I think it'll be easier this solution than the various hacks around